# mySQL выборка значения методом LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, выборка, escape

Добрый вечер, вопрос заключается в том что мне надо получить данные из базы однако  оператор работает не корректно, т.е надо получить все записи у которы `id` начинаются с определённых чисел, однако в данном `id` имеются также значения разделённые слешем `200/20` или `200/33`. Как мне правильно сделать выборку чтобы получал все записи у которых `id` равен числу (нпр - 200),так же должны учитыватся цыфры до слеша, что после слеша- нам не интерестно) например:
`SELECT .... WHERE order LIKE '200%'` должно выбирать как 200 так же и 200/20..
Давно я делал такие выборки и всё работало без погрешностей, однако уже не помню как надо правильно написать запрос,поиски не помогли
Зараннее благодарен

Comment: Да, правильно WHERE `variable` LIKE '200%'

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick да это понятно, однако выбирает только записи по ID 200, а вот 200/33 не получает

Comment: Можно попробовать variable LIKE '200' OR variable LIKE '200/%'

Comment: _выбирает только записи по ID 200, а вот 200/33 не получает_ Не воспроизводится. Демо-скрипт проблемы - в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Какой тип поля и БД у вас? Для VARCHAR (mysql) запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id LIKE '200%'
```

Работет вполне нормально и возвращает все значения, в том числе и 200/33, 200/44 и тд

Comment: И для CHAR(X), и для TEXT, и даже для VARBINARY(x) - тоже нормально всё. Ну а чисельный тип или даты-времени там быть не может.